# pyOpt nested optimization

Tags: python, optimization

Is it possible to perform nested optimization in pyOpt?

For example:

- let `x` be a design variable
- let `f()` an objective function
- let `max(h(x))< C` be a constraint, `h()` a function, known constant `C`,`max(h(x))` found via another optimization instance

Example of "outer" objfunc in pyOpt:

```
def __objfunc(x,**kwargs):
    f=x**2

    g=[0.0]
    g[0]=maxValueViaOptimization(x)-10 #inequality constraint

    fail=0
    return f,g,fail
```

`maxValueViaOptimization()` a function performing a separate optimization via pyOpt (finds max value of `h(x)`), returns float

Comment: This is called bi-level optimization. A very specialized area.

Comment: Are you aware of any Python libraries capable of solving such instances?

Comment: If the inner problem does not alter any of the outer variables (eg x) then you may be able just calling a function and use some derivative free solver.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen you were right, the inner problem does not affect execution of the outer one, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exactly what @Erwin Kalvelagen said.

> If the inner problem does not alter any of the outer variables (eg x) then >you may be able just calling a function and use some derivative free solver. >– @ErwinKalvelagen Jan 20 at 14:34